# Json in Perl error in opensips

Tags: json, perl, opensips

What is the difference between json and json::PP in Perl?

I meet this error when use Json and Json:PP when writing perl script in opensips

```
ERROR:core:XS_OpenSIPS__Message_log: 
perl warning: Prototype mismatch: sub main::decode_json ($) vs none.
```

I have problem with these codes:

```
my %postObject = ("callId" => $callID);
$postObject{'endTime'} = time() . "";
$postObject{'key'} = "12345@qwerty";
my $post_data = encode_json \%postObject;
```

Comment: Please show the corresponding [`use`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) statement for your JSON module. Your code works fine with both [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) and [`JSON::PP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::PP) on my machine (Ubuntu 17.10, Perl version 5.26.1). What version of Perl are you using?

Comment: i am using perl (v5.20.2) in Debian 7.11 (64 bit) with use ```use JSON::PP; ``` in my script.

Answer (score 2):

The "Prototype mismatch" warning typically means that you've defined a `sub` twice in some way, and the two definitions' prototypes don't match.

Do you have a `sub decode_json ($)` in your main code somewhere? If you do, I'd suggest removing or renaming it, because it is conflicting with `decode_json` from one of the `JSON` modules. If you don't, then you may be getting a second `decode_json` from another module you are loading, in which case you'd have to track that down, or provide us with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

I'd strongly recommend turning on [`warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html), because then you will additionally get "Subroutine redefined" warnings to help you track the issue down.